# adding UITapGestureRecognizer to html content

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView in which sometimes it loads up images, and I want to add a UITapGestureRecognizer to this image so that when I press it, it brings the full view of the image in full screen. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't :)

Make the image a link and then detect this in your UIWebView's delegate's [webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView%3ashouldStartLoadWithRequest%3anavigationType%3a)

When you detect a press on the image, show a new view infront of your webview containing the image.

Comment: The delegate method should get called for you by the web view. What have you tried so far?